# Histogram equalization without extreme values

Tags: python, histogram, cdf

Is it possible to make a histogram equalization without the extreme values 0 and 255?

Specifically I have an image, in which many pixels are zero. More than half of all pixels are zero. So if I do a histogram equalization there I shift basically the value 1 up to value 240 which is exactly the opposite what I want to do with a histogram equalization.
So is there a method to only calculate the histogram equalization between values 1 and 254?

At the moment my code looks the following:

```
flat = image.flatten()

# get image histogram
image_histogram, bins = np.histogram(flat, bins=range(0, number_bins), density=True)

cdf = image_histogram.cumsum() # cumulative distribution function
cdf = 255 * cdf /cdf.max() # normalize
cdf = cdf.astype('uint8')

# use linear interpolation of cdf to find new pixel values
image_equalized = np.interp(flat, bins[:-1], cdf)

image_equalized =  image_equalized.reshape(image.shape), cdf
```

Thanks

Comment: I am on the phone right now so I can't really try anything, but what would happens if there are NaNs in the data? Would it still work? If so you could replace the undesired nrs by NaN, and do the normalization, and then place them back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to filter out the *unwanted* values before we make the histogram, and then make a *"conversion table"* from a non-normalized pixel to a normalized pixel.

```
import numpy as np

# generate random image
image = np.random.randint(0, 256, (32, 32))

# flatten image
flat = image.flatten()

# get image histogram
image_histogram, bins = np.histogram(flat[np.where((flat != 0) & (flat != 255))[0]],
                                     bins=range(0, 10),
                                     density=True)

cdf = image_histogram.cumsum() # cumulative distribution function
cdf = 255 * cdf /cdf.max() # normalize
cdf = cdf.astype('uint8')

# use linear interpolation of cdf to find new pixel values
# we make a list conversion_table, where the index is the original pixel value,
# and the value is the histogram normalized pixel value
conversion_table = np.interp([i for i in range(0, 256)], bins[:-1], cdf)
# replace unwanted values by original
conversion_table[0] = 0
conversion_table[-1] = 255
image_equalized = np.array([conversion_table[pixel] for pixel in flat])

image_equalized =  image_equalized.reshape(image.shape), cdf
```

**disclaimer**: I have absolutely no experience whatsoever with image processing, so I have no idea about the validity :)